# Angular2 application call node.js function

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cors, preflight

Ok so I have an `Angular2` application running on `http://localhost:4200/`, Inside this app I'm trying to call a function located in a seperate `node.js` application currently running on `http://localhost:3000/`

My call from the `Angular2` application:

```
deletePhoto(photoId: string) {

    var options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200'
        })
    });

    let url = `http://localhost:3000/delete?photoId=${photoId}`;

    this.http.post(url, options).subscribe(response => {
        let user = response.json()
        console.log(user);
    },
        err => {
            console.log('Unable to call delete photo', err);
        });

}
```

And this is my `node.js` function :

```
var express = require('express')

var app = express();

app.post('/delete', function (req, res) {

    req.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

    var photoId = req.query['photoId'];
    //var userId = req.query['userId'];
    res.json({ "photoId": photoId, "test": "Testing node server" })
})
```

However the error I receive in the browser is:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Now after googling this error, I read I needed to set the header on the requested resource so I added the `req.setHeader` on my `node` method but still with no avail, I did also set it within my `Angular2` app to see if that's what it meant but sadly same result.

I have read up on `cors` but unfortunately I'm still confused by it.

Comment: If you're running angular-cli there is a proxy setup that they describe here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli#proxy-to-backend

Comment: If setting the proxy does'nt help you as a workaround you can temporarily disable this browser feature using this chrome plugin. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-GB

Comment: Ok so I added the proxy, configured the start setting within the package.json file yet the issue still remains, If i disabled the browser features then when I eventually go to production with this and I re-enable the features then the issue will just come back will it not?

Comment: You will only have issues if your endpoint is a different host,  so yes if you require CORS then you should solve for it in your development,  but if you just plan to build and place your angular app(dist) under the same domain you can proxy for dev and in prod it will just be relative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must also add code to handle the OPTIONS request that browsers send for [CORS preflights](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests):

```
app.options('/delete', function(req, res) {
    res.send(200);
});
```

That addition just causes your Node app send a `200` response with no body with all the necessary `Access-Control-*` response headers.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I just added the script you provided to the node application so I have the app.options('/delete' and the app.post('/delete' but yet the issue still remains..

Comment: Ok getting closer, I'm not getting the error 
"TypeError: req.setHeader is not a function which is returned after calling it

Comment: You need to make sure to put that code and the snippet from the question in your app code before any other Express routing your app does—as near to the top as you can, basically.

Comment: Yeah you got a typo there—`req.setHeader` should be **`res.`** instead.

Comment: Yep, It's right at the top, look at my other comment, I think we're getting closer to resolving it, when I call it I now get TypeError: req.setHeader is not a function

Comment: Yes you need to change your code to **res**.`setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');`, right?

Comment: Done, now I get Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://evil.com/, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: So that message you cite would indicates you’ve fixed the problem you posted about in the question, and now you have a different problem that probably should be a different question. But anyway that message indicates that some other part of your code is also setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` (to `http://evil.com`?…)—so you need to figure out what part of your code is doing that, and remove it.

Comment: Your comments for the question mention you had set up proxy set up, and some some browser extension enabled to avoid CORS checks. If so you need to make sure to not use that proxy and to turn off that browser extension.

Comment: I've removed the proxy setup, and also made sure cors was enabled within my browser, the only things I can think of within my project which could make additional http calls are Google Recaptcha, AngularFire2, and Cloudinary but I've just commented all of those configurations out, cleaned the cache and rebuilt the project yet the error is there..  further more of this error it's linked to:  XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=AIzaSyDCViGlCPATc-B7C4ZbFiYaKo5djbJAZgY

Comment: I think you may need to restart your browser and/or try in another browser. Otherwise I guess I’m at a loss because have absolutely no idea what else would be causing you to see that `http://evil.com` thing