# CORS issue React/nodejs : origin: '*' doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, node.js, request, cross-domain

i developping an app using react as frontend, node js as backend and my sql as database. when i'm filling a form to be sent to database trought node js i'm not finding all the data ( it works for some user and some not), secondly i found that i have CORS error, but even if i try to add `app.use(cors({origin: '*',methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",}));` i get the error

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.mehdi.com/api/submit-form' from origin 'https://experiments.mehdi.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`.

Knowing that my api (backend) is : `https://api.mehdi.com/api/submit-form`

and my front end is : `https://experiments.mehdi.com`

and both are hosted on the same server, is there a solution that i could try to resolve that , and thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js CORS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031758/node-js-cors-error)

Comment: @GreenDev no unfortunately that didn't solve my problem i tired to add ```const corsOpts = {
  origin: '*',

  methods: [
    'GET',
    'POST',
  ],

  allowedHeaders: [
    'Content-Type',
  ],
};

app.use(cors(corsOpts));``` but still not working